# ACF field is displayed in all categories Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In the field group settings, I specified to display the field in only one category. That is, in the rule, I selected Category equal to the corresponding category from the list.

For the test in the arhive.php template, I output:

```
$fields_type = acf_get_field(‘type’);
print_r($fields_type);
```

This array is displayed in all categories. How can I make it so that the fields are displayed only in those frontend categories that I have selected in the admin panel settings?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `is_category()` function to add display condition in `archive.php`:

```php
if(is_category(CATEGORY_ID)) {
    $fields_type = acf_get_field(‘type’);
    print_r($fields_type);
}
```

**Note**: Replace **CATEGORY_ID** with your category ID or slug that you want this field can displayed.

Comment: That's what I originally thought to do.
But, it would be logical that the acf_get_field function would contain such a parameter in the array that indicates the rule for binding to a category or to another object.